# Can Slick Delete/Update DB Query return Negative Integer Values as the result

Tags: database, scala, slick

Normally when we perfom a Scala Slick Delete/Update query it return 0 if the delete/update is unsuccessfull due to not found the required id.
On the other hand if the delete/update is successfull it will return the number of rows that affected with the delete/update operation.

```
  override def deletePerson(id: Long): Future[Int] = {
    db.run(personQuery.filter(_.id === id).delete)
  }
```

For example the above slcik query will return 0 if the requested id is not found for the  deletion. Moroever it will return possitive value which is equal to the deleted rows if any rows deleted.

What I need to know is that can there be negative values (ex: -1) return as the result for a delete/update result in scala slick. Because I need to perform a validation based on the return result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You won't see -1 from that query.

Slick uses an API called JDBC at a lower-level. It defines the results from update and delete statements. You can look into the specification to see what results are returned from `executeUpdate` at that level. You can find the specification at: https://www.jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=221

The API is implemented by a driver for your database. That driver will be compliant with the specification.

However, there are a couple of comments on this:

- I'm not sure what will happen if you have a query that returns more than `Integer.MAX_INT` results. Probably unlikely for the query you have shown.
- The JDBC API does allow for -1 from a `getUpdateCount` call, but to get that you'd need to be doing something low-level level (lower than the example you have).

Answer (score 1):

It's the number of affected rows, so I doubt it. If there is anything wrong your query, it would return errors rather than a negative number.

Still, I wouldn't recommend to do things like `!= 0` to check if query succeeded. `result > 0` would be better, but the best would be another query that actually validates something, that you run in the same transaction as insert/update.